# What is the best way to save and load an activity log in PHP?

Tags: php

Before I begin, THIS IS AN ASSIGNMENT. I am just after a helping hand an some guidance :)

I am developing a gym membership website which allows users to register, login, and book an activity.

I have everything working, besides the activity booking system, and that is what I need guidance with. I have a single txt file that contains an activity log of each activities name, time, how many can attend in total. I would like to add to the end of each activities line of who is attending exactly. Therefore, allowing users to book the activity, which adds their username to the activity.

This is exactly how I currently have my activity.txt file printing (besides the 'Book' buttons on the far right.

```
NumberOne       3       Wednesday 8am       (BOOK)
NumberTwo       7       Thursday 10am       (BOOK)
NumberThree     20      Monday 1pm          (BOOK)
NumberFour      15      Tuesday 5pm         (BOOK)
```

Basically, what I need guidance with is the 'Book' buttons. Once a 'Book' button is pressed, it will book the user in to the activity.

This is how my activity.txt file currently looks:

```
NumberOne,3,Wednesday 8am
NumberTwo,7,Thursday 10am
NumberThree,20,Monday 1pm
NumberFour,15,Tuesday 5pm
```

And this is the code I currently have that is printing the activities:

```
function bookActivity()
{
 $fileContentsArray = file("activity.txt");
    echo "<table>";
    foreach($fileContentsArray as $one_persons_data)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  $splitted = preg_split('/,/', $one_persons_data);
  foreach ($splitted as $one) 
  {
    echo "<td>$one</td>";
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Below is my users.txt file if needed. All passwords are saved in MD5

```
jiten:3fc0a7acf087f549ac2b266baf94b8b1
jb:3fc0a7acf087f549ac2b266baf94b8b1
test:bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb
joeBlogg:bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb
userX:bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb
userY:bed128365216c019988915ed3add75fb
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Very confused on how to do this.

Comment: This would be one of those cases where a database comes in handy.

Comment: Agreed. Although, we are forced to use a txt file :(

Comment: what your trying to do

Comment: `csv` is the best suited format, imho.

Comment: Yeah. Although unfortunealty we have to use a txt file. Seems quite unfair to me since XML or CSV is industry standard over a stupid txt file.

Comment: @FDL - I'll update my post with the users.txt file aswel, thanks for asking. Yes, I can add anything to my activity.txt file like a unique ID.

Comment: you can serialize data structures to text files. were you given a requirement to just flat files per say or?

Comment: well, `csv` is text... just not tab separated as you currently have. I would even use `json` since it is handled very easy in `php`, and you can add complexer data structures. ie: add an array of usernames to every booking

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer - My txt file is not tab separated, it is just printing out in a table as you can see in the first example. My txt file is comma separated like in the example.

Comment: [comma-separated values (CSV) is also sometimes called character-separated values, because the separator character does not have to be a comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Actually when using MS Excel, CSV are written with Tab characters as the separator.

Comment: Whoever’s forcing you to use just a **.txt** file is a nugget. Why? What course is this? If it’s anything computer science-related and they’re forcing you to use the wrong tool for the job like this, then I’d question your lecturer/school.

Comment: I hope that md5 was not forced upon you tho...

Comment: @MartinBean - Thanks for the heads up. It's a Web Programming subject concentrating on HTML, CSS and PHP. We were forced to use .txt files, although we had the opportunity to use XML. If we chose to use XML, we would receive no help from our lecturer, and we would have to research everything ourselves.

Comment: @DarkBee - Haha... It sure was

Comment: @JadeMulholland I’m lost for words. They’re are plenty of other things your lecturer could have used to demonstrate reading and writing from text files than an entire gym membership booking system.

Comment: I would wheep the whole time while implementing this according to this teachers norm..

Comment: @MartinBean - Would have been fantastic to learn some more advanced technologies such as MySQL, and some better security for things like this. So far, the PHP will benefit my future, although the security we are using and the txt files will be of no use at all.
I mainly took this course to help with my PHP development along with databases. Was a very big let down :(

Comment: Did you know plain MD5-hashing of passwords is utterly insecure? The passwords are `passw0rd` and `qwerty123`. 1. Read. ([this resource](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for example) 2. Use a strong hash algorithm. 3. .. and salt it.

Comment: @Kaii : [password_hash](http://be2.php.net/password_hash) creates secures hashes with random salts for u

Comment: @Kaii - Thanks for your help. I'll have to consider implementing a better form of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough guideline (I won't go in the specifics because it's homework after all) and I'll keep the assumption you're not allowed to use anything different than text file but can create/delete as many of them as you wish.

1. parse the activity txt file, using `file(...)` with the proper flags set
2. build an array which key are the activities "IDs" (numberOne, numberTwo, etc) and value is another array containing the activity details. You may find handy `explode()` here.
3. For each activity create a file dedicated to it (if it doesn't exist already, of course). This file will contain the names of the registered users that booked the activity. I suggest you to write one name per line in this file.
4. when somebody press the "book activity" button, you'll have to do the following steps:

   - Check if the requested activity file exists. if it doesn't, create
     an empty one.
   - Count the current number of booked users and compare it with the maximum allowed
   - If it's less, add the new user to the file, otherwise reject the booking
5. To show the list of the booked users, simply read the file contents from each activity file. You may find useful `implode()` this time.

I hope this will help you finding the right track. A last note, text files aren't designed to do this: a small database is easier to use, more fun to learn and more useful for your future.

References:

- [How to create a file with `file_put_contents(...)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [How to read a file with `file(...)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: Thanks STT LCU for your fantastic guidance. And thank you Martin Bean for your edit.
Still very new to PHP, so I'll have to try and implement this the best I can... And if I can haha.

Comment: Although, not to sure on how to create a .txt file

Comment: @JadeMulholland see my edit, it'll help you. Also, google is really your friend: try to search for "write a file PHP" ;)

Comment: Thanks, the edit cleared everything up. file_put_contents seems like a fantastic function and I am actually quite curious. I think I'll definitely have to give this method a shot!

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. This doesn't sound like a log; it sounds like a file-based database.
2. If allowed, use a .csv file (not .txt) and parse it using [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).
3. Since it's your database you'll need to write to it. You can use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) for that.

(FWIW, your .txt file is already a csv, you're just not treating it that way.)

Per the specific question: Clicking "Book" just needs to pass the Course Name to a script that will add the current user to that course (if they haven't already registered). You can pass the course name using POST (HTML forms) or, more simply, GET (links and query parameters).

Using links (GET) might look like this:

```
    $bookingUrl = "register.php?courseName=".urlencode($courseName);
```

Using a form (POST) might look like this:

```
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?= $courseName; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Book" />
    </form>
```

Another answer mentioned using separate files to track registrations per course, but I don't think that's necessary; just use one. It's helpful to think of what you're really tracking:

1. Available Courses, "courses.txt": Course Name, Course Time (got it)
2. Users, "users.txt": Username, Password (got it)
3. Registrations, "registrations.txt": Username, Course Name (don't got it)

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Wasn't to sure on the differences between csv and txt. Very helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: I think I have decided to use this method since I have no idea how to work with multiple txt files, and not to sure how to create them. Thanks for your help Dan.

Comment: Look into all the "f" (file) functions, most importantly: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php), [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), fputcsv, and fgetcsv.

Comment: Yes, the idea of using 3 files is the most similar to a real database structure (where we'll have the course table, the users table, and the registrations table). My idea was more geared towards an approach harder to build but easier to use and parse.

Comment: How would you recommend I save the users name to the file? For example, you can see how my activities.txt file is within my question. Where abouts would I add all of the usernames?

Comment: It seems like you are already using a colon-delimited file to store usernames and passwords, no? Just pull from there. Whoever is currently logged in when the booking link is clicked is the username you need to look up.

Comment: @DanSchmidt - Yes, I already have a username and password file. The username is saved as a global variable once they are signed in. Although, where should I save all the usernames who are registered to a certain booking?